# Distinct column names from comma separated string

Tags: sql-server

Two reports are using columns of a table with following queries

```
SELECT [Employee Name], [Email_ID], [Region], [DOB], [Joining Date], [Gross Salary]   FROM [tblC6FD_Data_15_EmployeeData]   ORDER BY [Employee Name] ASC, [Email_ID] ASC, [Region] ASC, [DOB] ASC, [Joining Date] ASC, [Gross Salary] ASC
```

---

```
SELECT [Employee Name], [Region], [Email_ID], [DOB], [Leaving Date], [Basic Salary]   FROM [tblC6FD_Data_15_EmployeeData]   ORDER BY [Employee Name] ASC, [Region] ASC, [Email_ID] ASC, [DOB] ASC, [Joining Date] ASC, [Gross Salary] ASC
```

and i want distinct columns list of table that is being used by reports

**Expected output**

```
Employee 
Email 
Region 
DOB 
Joining Date 
Gross Salary 
Leaving Date 
Basic Salary
```

I have one idea to split it with `,` but a lot of confusions and complexity to avoid other strings after **from** keyword.

Can anyone suggest a simple solution.

Comment: In other words - you want to parse query text and return columns from SELECT clause, right?

Comment: yes, and you can see there are some columns same in both query but i want distinct values

Comment: Note to all of you doing edits on this question: **The two queries are stored as values in a table** Please don't format the values with linebreaks etc.

Comment: I am giving line break for clarity only

Comment: @pavezalam Thats alright, I was referring to the formating by others that put linebreak in your values.

Answer (score 1):

i wrapped up it with following solution

```
  declare @str nvarchar(max)
  set @str = (select ReportSQL from tblRB_Report where PK_ReportID = 15)
  set @str = REPLACE(@str,']',' ')
   set @str = REPLACE(@str,'[',' ')
  set @str = REPLACE(@str,'select',' ')

 set @str = SUBSTRING(@str,0,charindex('FROM',@str))
  --print @str


sELECT * from  [dbo].[StringSplit](@str,',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this?? this gives you list of column names

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[COLUMNS] c  WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

Comment: you answer is bouncer to me :-(

Comment: can you give a test data, exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

You have to use string functions for parsing, e.g. in C# it would be IndexOf() and Substring().

P.S. Seems this question is not related to sql-server btw.